# flutter TypeAheadField onSuggestionSelected not work in real android device but work on emulatur

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have a Flutter project in Android Studio
In this program there is a section to edit or add addresses
The list of countries is loaded, and after the user selects the desired country, then the list of provinces is loaded, and after the user selects a province, the list of cities in that province is loaded, and the user can choose his city.
This program works properly in the **emulator**

In the **emulator**, when the list of countries is loaded, by clicking the **mouse** on the country, that country is selected and the values of that country are displayed in the next box.
But in the **real mobile phone** (my device is xiaomi me 11 ultra), when I tap on the country, nothing happens and the program does not react
I am using and test both of
flutter_typeahead: ^4.0.0 and flutter_typeahead: ^4.8.0
but the problem still remains

my complete code is large and i can not paste here but shared here:
[link](https://mega.nz/file/H8AgUbZB#xfsfGC0ChMhNwMLxp57o_bvuWNk8PabYVgh1QPHiWlw)